# Access globally installed package via require in node

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `gulp` based build system. Currently I have some tasks, e.g. a task that is accessing `npm` (`require('npm')`) programmatically. In order to achieve it I need to specify `npm` in my `package.json` dependencies, so that `require` can find it inside `node_modules`. However `npm` is obviously available along with `node` & I also have `npm` installed globally (latest 3.x version of `npm`).

Is there a way to require a global instance of `npm`? I do the same stuff e.g. with other npm packages (I mean I have global package installed but I duplicate it in `package.json` to make it available via `require`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it by adding **NODE_PATH** to your environment variable eg:

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

After doing this you node should be able to find globally installed packages as well.

**NOTE:**`your node module path may defer.`

to make it permanent you can add the commmand to your `~/.bashrc` file